# change background of DataGrid CheckBox Column for validation errors

Tags: wpf, validation, checkbox, datagrid

(Visual Studio 2010)  I'm trying to perform validation on a `CheckBoxColumn` in a WPF datagrid.  I've set up a validation rule, and if it fails I want the cell background to turn red and have tooltip:

```
 <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Checked" >
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Binding>
                    <Binding Path="CheckProperty" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:CheckValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Binding>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" 
                              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

But when the validation fails, my cell style is completely ignored.  I'm actually used to this (but I never figured *why* it was ignored), so then I tried to use a `TemplateColumn` with a `Checkbox`, and there I can change the `CheckBox` border background, but still haven't figured out how to change the background color of the entire cell itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DataTrigger instead of Trigger Property:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Checked" Binding="{Binding CheckProperty}">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CheckProperty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CheckProperty}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```